# The Barr-Boole-Galois topos; a modification of sets to play well with schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, topos-theory

William Lawvere, in his 2015 CT talk "[Alexander Grothendieck & the Concept of Space](https://github.com/mattearnshaw/lawvere/blob/master/pdfs/2015-alexander-grothendieck-and-the-concept-of-space.pdf)", introduced the "Barr-Boole-Galois topos", which plays the role that sets do for topological spaces (with respect to [axiomatic cohesion](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cohesive+topos)), but for schemes instead (emphasis added):

> In a topos of set-valued functors on the category of finitely-presentable algebras, each space X has, thanks to Yoneda, an 'inside' whose objects are (in general singular) figures of representable shapes, with incidence relations given by commutative triangles. This can be viewed as a discretely-opfibered category, but such is equivalent to a set-valued functor. [I disagree with the term 'functor of points' for this, because it is a functor whose actual values include all the figures of X. Of course, 'points' of some other space associated to X may represent figures in X, but for X itself the points of it are just the restriction of X to the category of finite field extensions. That category generates the Boolean part of the big topos. The usual definition of point is unwieldy because it amounts to taking the non-exact direct limit of that restricted points functor. In general, this Boolean topos is much better suited than the category of abstract sets to serve as 'base topos' in the case of non-algebraically closed ground field. Conflating 'figures in X' with 'points of X' has a sort of science fiction air he probably did not intend. Volterra called them 'elements'.] A better version of the 'underlying topological space' is internal to the **Barr-Boole-Galois topos** where the actual points functor lands; this choice is also necessary for a product preserving components functor.

It is evidently the "boolean part" of the topos of sheaves on the Big Zariski site. So one could think of it as modifying $\mathrm{Set}$ to some other category $C$. For one thing, this modification gives an actual contravariant adjunction $\mathrm{Sch}/\mathrm{Spec}(k) \leftrightarrow C$. But it gets much better: this adjunction has further adjoints on either side of each of the functors, and it serves as a setting for Lawvere's cohesion.

1) Can anyone define the "boolean part" of a topos? It should be a subtopos of a topos which is a boolean topos.

2) According to Lawvere, Barr showed that the boolean part of the big Zariski topos over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ is generated by sheaves on finite $k$-algebras. Does anyone know of a reference for this?

Vaguely, what is going on with Lawvere's definition that I am trying to work out is that Schemes over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ experience a cohesion, except for that sets must be modified to something like sheaves over the opposite category of the site of finite $k$-algebras to get this cohesion setup. One of these functors in the cohesion setup is like "the improved version of $\mathrm{Spec}$".

Comment: "Boolean part" is not really a standard terminology, so I can't guarantee that what follows is correct without a reference to something written by Lawvere about this. But if it is a boolean subtopos, I would assume it is the double negation subtopos. (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double+negation#topology)

Comment: It could be something related to the Barr cover/Barr embedding theorem. Looking through Barr's [topos theory papers](http://www.math.mcgill.ca/barr/#toposes) I can't see anything obvious (Mike Barr keeps all his papers/books on his website to make them freely accessible)

Comment: You gotta be a little careful with the go-to example: It is evident that the discrete space functor $\mathrm{Set} \to \mathrm{Top}$ does not preserve products, because for example Cantor space $2^\mathbb{N}$ is not discrete. You probably want, instead of $\mathrm{Top}$, the category of locally connected spaces, where for example the product topology is refined by applying coreflection $\mathrm{Top} \to \mathrm{LocConn}$ (retopologize by letting connected components of opens be open).

Comment: @ToddTrimble. Thanks, I'll fix shortly. Or alternatively, could one modify Set instead of modifying Top?

Comment: I'm not aware of any such modification, and I kind of doubt it since you'd still need conditions on monads/comonads on $\mathrm{Top}$ that come from the string of adjunctions.

Comment: Question 2) feels a little bit like a baby version of Clausen and Scholze's condensed mathematics, where the base is changed from set to something a bit more...exotic.

Comment: @DavidRoberts can you elaborate a bit, maybe with analogies? The Barr-Boole-Galois topos is to Schemes as what is to what, in condensed mathematics?

Comment: Maybe schemes to condensed schemes is a cohesion setup - is that what you were suggesting? Of course, we already have a geometric morphism between schemes and condensed schemes. I think I'll check for further adjoints on each side.

Comment: Yes, something like cohesion, I guess. In the condensed world, the category of sheaves on a point (Set, in the usual setup) is the proétale site of the point, which is the weird big thing that contains all the Stone spaces etc.

Comment: I don't think it answers the question but the paper http://cahierstgdc.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Menni_55-2.pdf seems related.